# Node.js Request params undefined

Tags: typescript, express, parameters, request

I have a get route that receives two parameters "limit" and "page".

```
router.get('/:limit/:page', userController.list);

class UserController{
    public list(req:Request, res:Response): void{
        const limit:number = +req.params.limit || 25;
        const page:number = +req.params.page || 0; }
}
export const userController: UserController = new UserController();
```

The problem is these params are undefined when I make the request from postman.

```
localhost:3000/api/users/?limit=2&page=1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing [query parameters](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query) but your route wants [route parameters](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters).

To use route parameters, your request should look like `http://localhost:3000/api/users/2/1`

Typically though, pagination *is* passed as query parameters in which case your route handler should look like this

```ts
import { Request, Response } from "express";

interface PaginationQuery {
  limit?: number;
  page?: number;
}

type PaginationRequest = Request<{}, any, any, PaginationQuery>;

router.get('/', userController.list);

class UserController{
  public list(req: PaginationRequest, res: Response): void {
    const limit = req.query.limit ?? 25;
    const page = req.query.page ?? 0;
  }
}
```